# .Net : Unzipping Gz file : Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Tags: c#, .net, sharpziplib

So I have been using the method below to unzip .gz files and its been working really well.

It uses SharpZip.

Now I am using larger files and it seems to be trying to unzip everything in memory giving me : Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program..

Should I be reading each line instead of using **ReadToEnd**()?

```
public static void DecompressGZip(String fileRoot, String destRoot)
        {
            using FileStream fileStram = new FileStream(fileRoot, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using GZipInputStream zipStream = new GZipInputStream(fileStram);
            using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(zipStream);
            var data = sr.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText(destRoot, data);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just `.CopyTo`? Reading whole file to immediately write it back (especially with potentially converting from/to UTF8) does not sound like a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @alexei-levenkov suggests, CopyTo will chunk the copy without using up all the memory.

Bonus points, use the Async version for the threading goodness.

```
public static async Task DecompressGZipAsync(String fileRoot, String destRoot)
{
      using (Stream zipFileStream = File.OpenRead(fileRoot))
      using (Stream outputFileStream = File.Create(destRoot))
      using (Stream zipStream = new GZipInputStream(zipFileStream))
      {
            await zipStream.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
      }
}
```